# Trouble with regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, text-parsing, string-parsing

I am trying to write a script to parse a trial balance sheet. The layout of each line in the file is always the same but I am having an issue getting my regex to match properly. The first 10 characters of the line are always the account number. Here is an example:

```
0000000099 S000 Doe, John  00 1,243.22  01/01/1901
```

I am trying to capture each of these to columns to a separate variable, but my expressions aren't working.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $filename = "S:\\TELLERS\\GalaxyDown\\tbal";
my $answer   = undef;
open(FIN, $filename) || die "File not found";

do {
    print "Enter an account number: ";
    chomp(my $acctNum = <STDIN>);

    if ($acctNum =~ /\d{1,10}/) {
        $acctNum = pad_zeros($acctNum);

        #print "$acctNum\n";    #test to make sure the padding extends the account
                                #number to 10 digits - comment out after verification

        while (<FIN>) {

            #print "$_\n";

            if (m/(^[0-9]{10}/) {
                print "Passed\n";
            }
            else {
                print "Failed\n";
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        print "Invalid account number. Please try again.\n";
    }
    print "Would you like to view another account balance? (yes/no): ";
    chomp($answer = lc <STDIN>);

} while ($answer ne "no");

sub pad_zeros {
    my $optimal_length = 10;
    my $num            = shift;
    $num =~ s/^(\d+)$/("0"x($optimal_length-length$1)).$1/e;
    return $num;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: given that it's constant, would it be just as easy to use perl's split function, and split on the spaces? I think it would be a whole lot more straight forward.

Comment: might be a cut n paste but i believe there is a typo here: if (m/(^[0-9]{10}/){ (an extra `(` before the `^`

Comment: which regex is failing? and what is the input when it fails?

Comment: unfortunately split won't work because there can be a space in the name field. That was my original thought. The regex is failing to match anything but the extra ( may be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pad_zeros` function is really a longhand form for `sprintf '%0*d', $optimal_length, $num`.

Your `while(<FIN>)` loop reads all lines in the tbal file and prints for each line in that file whether that line starts with a ten digit number, but only for the first account number entered (The readline operator `<>` is effectively an iterator, and is exhausted after you read all lines). The solution is to open the filehandle inside the `if` branch.

There are a few other things that could be improved:

- You don't need to initialize a scalar variable with `undef`: this is already their default value.
- To open a filehandle, you should (1) use a normal variable for that file handle, and (2) use the three-argument-form of `open`:

  ```
  open my $fin, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
  ```

  where `$!` contains the reason why the `open` failed. Specifying an explicit mode `<` makes a few corner cases more secure.
- Backslashing paths is ugly, but Windows handles normal slashes just fine → `S:/TELLERS/...`.

To split a line into multiple fields, you have to think about the exact format: Is each field seperated by a common seperator, e.g a space? In that case,

```
my @fields = split " ", $line;
```

would do the trick. Change the `" "` to a regex determining the seperator for a different seperator (tabs, commas, etc).

However, your format doesn't look that simple, because the comma after the surname likely isn't part of the data of the surname field (?)

A regex like

```
my $regex = qr{\A
  \s* ([0-9]{10})
  \s+ (S[0-9]{3})
  \s+ ([^,]+),            # the surname
  \s+ ([^0-9]+(?<!\s))    # other names
  \s+ ([0-9]{2})
  \s+ ([0-9,]+\.[0-9]{2})
  \s+ ([0-9]{2})
   /  ([0-9]{2})
   /  ([0-9]{4})
   \s*\z
}x;
my @fields = $line =~ $regex;
```

might be better, but that depends on the *exact* format you have.

Matching names is difficult, as some peoply may have more than one name. Consider the entries `Gogh, Vincent van` or `Tucker, Charles III.` I decided to match “any non-numeric string that doesn't end with a space character”.

Comment: I'm going to have to play with your regex a little, but it might work out if the substr method doesn't pan out for me. Split won't work because of the name field, and I have no control over the delimiters in the report.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting any points for this. [Amon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934225/368630) has pretty much nailed it, and given you everything you need to know including some wonderful suggestions.

Your say your account line looks like this:

```
0000000099 S000 Doe, John  00 1,243.22  01/01/1901
```

The problem is that spaces can be used as part of a name. *Mary Jane Von Corona* has four spaces in it. However, it's a first name, *Mary Jane*, and a last name *Von Corona*. How do I know where the name is split?

The best way is to either use a fixed length field, or use a separator that isn't in the file.

```
0000000099|S000|Doe|John|00|1,243.22|01/01/1901
```

Here, I'm using `|` as field separators. I could do this:

```
my ( $account,   $something,   $something2,
     $last,      $first,       $something3,
     $balance,   $date)                       = split /\|/, $line;
```

This is splitting the entire line in one shot on the `|`.

If fields had a fixed width, I could use the [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function to pull apart the various fields in this line:

```
my $account = substr( $line, 0, 10 );   #First 10 characters is always the account number
```

I would also recommend using [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html). This way, you don't have to test various things like whether or not your file was successfully opened. Perl will automatically die (and usually with a nice error message) when things like this happen.

Comment: `Mary Jane Von Corona` has *three* spaces and four fields :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing blatantly wrong with your code. You don't say what you mean by *"not working"*, but I notice that you are reading through the file multiple times to search for the input. Once the end of the file has been reached you need to either `seek` to the start again or reopen the file.

Here are some suggestions

- Don't use the `-w` command-line qualifier. `use warnings` is far better
- Use single quotes to delmit strings containing backslashes. Then they don't need escaping unless there is more than one of them together or they appear at the end of the string
- You would make a lot of seasoned Perl programmers a lot happier if you used `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` for your local identifiers
- It is current best practice to use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`. And you should put the `$!` into your `die` string so you can se *why* the open failed
- You check for `/\d{1,10}/` in your input, which tests whether the string *contains* a string of digits anywhere. You probably meant `/^\d{1,10}$/`
- `sub pad_zeroes` is better written as `sprintf '%0*d', $optimal_length, $_[0]`

Here is a suggested rewrite. I have altered the code to check whether the account specified by the input text has been read, which is presumably your intention.

**Note** that a sequential search through the file for every new account number entered is vastly inefficient and only feasible for a small data file or a one-off program. I recommend you use [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) together with a hash that indicates which element of the tied array to read to access a given account number.

**Note** It appears that your file uses fixed-width fields, i.e. the fields always start and end at the same character positions in the lines. If so, then rather than use regular expression to process the data you should use `substr` or `unpack`. Even better, the module [`Parse::FixedLength`](https://metacpan.org/module/Parse%3a%3aFixedLength) allows you simply to specify the length of each field and will do the rest of the work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'S:\TELLERS\GalaxyDown\tbal';
my $answer;

do {
    print "Enter an account number: ";
    chomp(my $acct_num = <STDIN>);

    if ($acct_num =~ /^\d{1,10}$/) {

        $acct_num = pad_zeroes($acct_num);

        #print "$acct_num\n";    #test to make sure the padding extends the account
                                 #number to 10 digits - comment out after verification

        open(my $fin, '<', $filename) || die "File not found: $!";
        while (<$fin>) {
            if (/^$acct_num/) {
              print "Passed\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print "Invalid account number. Please try again.\n";
    }
    print "Would you like to view another account balance? (yes/no): ";
    chomp($answer = lc <STDIN>);

} until $answer eq 'no';


sub pad_zeroes {
    my $optimal_length = 10;
    sprintf '%0*d', $optimal_length, $_[0];
}
```

Comment: substr or a similiar function may be my best bet. I was using them because I was unsure of the column widths at the time of posting.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check the full line you can use something like this:

```
  while(<FIN>){

        if( @a = (m/^\s*(\d{1,10})\s+(S\d+)\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s+(\d\d)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d\d?\/\d\d?\/(?:\d\d)\d\d)\s*/) ) {
            $a[0] = sprintf "%010d", $a[0];
            print "Account number:  $a[0]";
            print "Account series:  $a[1]";
            print "Account owner:   $a[3] $a[2]";
            print "Account type:    $a[4]";
            print "Account balance: $a[5]";
            print "Account date:    $a[6]";
        } else {
            print "Failed\n";
        }
```

Any deviation from the required format will print "Failed"
You can make adjustments according to your needs.